# Is storing a Unix timestamp a bad idea in the long term

Tags: mysql, database, go

I've recently started working on a new application and I need to be able to compare times that the user has been active so basically my logic will be something like:

```
func pseudo (user string) {
    v := GET Timestamp FROM users;

    if currentTimestamp - 1800 < dbTimestamp
        // Do something
```

I've though about using Unix timestamps, in specific the number of seconds. However I'm not sure if storing this will become a problem as it only grows and I realize it will take a while to add more digits it does not feel like it's the best for performance reasons. Is storing and comparing a Unix timestamp a good idea for long term applications?

**Side note:**

My application is written in go so while I can store datetime, I have to extract the datetime from the database and attempt to use the atrocious layout numbers and it becomes more complicated attempting to format it to work with the layout numbers.

Comment: You're worried about the timestamp overflowing 32bits in the year 2106?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 31,536,000 seconds in a year, so it will take over 269 years before another digit is added to unix timestamps.

```
(10,000,000,000 - 1,510,798,414) / 31,536,000 = 269.1908
```

So, on that count I'd say you're good for a while.

Depending on the database column type that you're using, a more immediate problem might be that from January 19, 2038 onward, you will no longer be able to store your timestamps in a signed 32 bit integer as they have a max value of 2,147,483,647.

So, I'd say: put a sticky note on your monitor to change your database column type on January 18, 2038. If you're using an unsigned 32 bit integer type, you're good until 2106.

Comment: "So, on that count I'd say you're good for a while." In fairness, that's what folks probably said to themselves in 1970. 

Comment: @ceejayoz And how right they were!

Answer (score 1):

I guess number of bits is not a big deal - 64bits will be enough for so long time, that all ourdays computer industry will be totally obsolete.

But there's more serious concern. Time is not so plain and linear. Sometimes you have leap seconds which breaks normal flow. Also timezones are sometimes get changed. So storing and working with time as int you have to deal with all strange issues. I definitely recommend switch special data types as in DB so in applications.

I have been using number of seconds for storing dates. That was my habit since I worked with MySQL 3.x and 4.x - they had awful support for dates, so it was easier to realize in app and keep only integer value. But as I've said I had to go through other issues it's not too hard but takes time and error-prone. If at the start of the project you have to keep only a time, later you'll need calculate intervals, then time with local options and so on.

So I recommend using special date time. Go has nice precision and maximum date is `219248499-12-06` - enough for us :). In PostgreSQL maximum year `294276 AD`.

Comment: Using Unix timestamps means timezone changes are irrelevant, and operating systems account for the leap seconds via their clocks. There's nothing wrong with storing one as an `INT`, but you're right that some of the special functionality around `DATETIME` can be helpful.

Comment: Vmany projects don’t require some advanced features. At start. But they became useful and successful and require integration with other systems. But later it’s more complicated so some basic features better to set io at start   Especially if they are easier to work than more primitive